# Backbone View Save (best practice)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript

If I have a class A that contains some properties a, b, and c, would it be ok it have a save method that is responsible for saving these attributes to the db.

```
class A extends Backbone.View
  ...
  save: ->
    @model.set
      a : someVal
      b : someVal
      c : someVal
    @model.save()
```

This seems like the most logical way to set it up, but would like to hear some suggestions on how you guys are doing it. Thanks!

Comment: Is that `@model.set` supposed to be a `@model.save`?

Comment: updated - added the save call to the save function (just forgot to add it initially). question still stands.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using slightly different approach. Usually I have several views, that edit various parts of the model, all those views have so-called `flush()` method (you named it `save()`), which sets data from inputs to the model. If they can't flush data because of validation, they show in place errors. Then I have the button like "Save", which flushes all the views and saves the model to the server (if all flushes succeeded). This button acts exactly as you describe.

The charm of Backbone is that it doesn't force you to do things in some specific way, like other frameworks often do, you're free to do it in whatever way you like.

Comment: so why do you prefer "flush" terminology over "save". i decided to use "save" because that is what the backbone method on the collection is called...